# rails dbconsole drops me into my 'test' database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

For some reason, when I run `rails dbconsole` command, it brings up my test database.  I think that I must have some file misconfigured. I don't even know where to start looking to correct this. Its really annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Config/database.yml would be the first place to look.
Make sure dev and test have different db names.

Comment: damn g, I looked there earlier, but mistake evaded my eyes before. Thanks!